# How can I use my users (non verified) addresses as senders with Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm writing a send to a friend feature and I need the from address to be the senders email to be a bit more personal. However, with Amazon SES it looks like I can only send from verified addresses.

I don't think this is an uncommon problem and was wondering how anyone else has solved this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, with Amazon SES it looks like I can only send from verified
> addresses.

That's correct, however, one of the historical flaws (and one of the main reasons for people becoming victims of email based fishing attacks so easily) with the [Simple Mail Transport Protocol (SMTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) is that the sender from the [mail transport agent's (MTA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transport_agent) point of view doesn't need to match the sender from the mail client point of view at all, see [About Header Fields](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SendingEmail.Raw.html#SendingEmail.Raw.headers):

> Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) specifies how email messages are
> to be sent by defining the mail envelope and some of its parameters,
> but it does not concern itself with the content of the message.
> Instead, the Internet Message Format (RFC 2822) defines how the
> message is to be constructed.

RFC 2822 defines the [Originator fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) to *indicate the mailbox(es) of the source of the message*:

> The "From:" field specifies the author(s) of the message, that is,
> the mailbox(es) of the person(s) or system(s) responsible for the
> writing of the message.  The "Sender:" field specifies the mailbox
> of the agent responsible for the actual transmission of the
> message.  For example, if a secretary were to send a message for
> another person, the mailbox of the secretary would appear in the
> "Sender:" field and the mailbox of the actual author would appear in
> the "From:" field.

### Solution

As outlined you'll simply need to supply the verified sender in the `Sender` header fields and can provide whatever `From` address you like (see [Appendix: Header Fields](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Headers.html) for a list of the supported fields).

#### Attention

For the aforementioned reasons, crafting your mail like so (albeit entirely valid) makes it much more likely to be classified as spam by involved mail transport systems - here's how AWS describes this issue within their [Whitepaper on Email Best Practices](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx2GBEOGDU758MG/New-Whitepaper-on-Email-Best-Practices):

> Think carefully about the addresses you send your email from. The
> “From” address will not only be visible to  recipients in their email
> client (including in the preview pane), but will also collect
> reputation at some ISPs. This,  along with the Subject line, will
> create the first impression a recipient will have of your email.

Therefore you should apply the available measures for [Authenticating Your Email](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SPFSenderIDDKIM.html) to improve your reputation in turn (which is highly recommended anyway of course).

Comment: Based on the discussion at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150255, this doesn't appear to be true.  (It may have been at the time and just isn't now.)

Comment: Agreed with @Isaac. In fact, I'm experimenting with this right now. Using a verified address in the `Sender` header and a non-verified address in the `From` header generates the following error: `554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: my_unverified_address@example.com`